# Is it good practice to store JSON object in cookie?

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

I have following object.

```
position = {
    latitude: 19.067863700000004,
    longitude: 72.9991898,
    pincode: 400701
}
```

I want to store value of latitude, longitude and pincode in cookie.

I know three ways.

i) store entire `position` object in cookie.(which is not recommended according to [this](https://blog.revathskumar.com/2014/07/why-you-should-not-store-json-in-cookie.html))

```
var pos = JSON.stringify(position);
document.cookie = "position=" + pos;
```

ii) create three cookie `latitude`, `longitude` and `pincode` and store respective value in respective cookie.

```
document.cookie = "latitude=" + position.latitude;
document.cookie = "longitude=" + position.longitude;
document.cookie = "pincode=" + position.pincode;
```

iii) create one cookie `position` and store value in this cookie is `19.067863700000004|72.9991898|400701`

```
var pos = position.latitude + "|" + position.longitude + "|" + position.pincode;
document.cookie = "position=" + pos;
```

My question is **which is best/ideal way to store cookie?**(Give a reason if possible)

Comment: What about local storage?

Comment: I want this data at page load time on server, So I can't use local storage.

Comment: What is best in your case: do you care about your code simplicity or do you care about network performance because the cookie is going to be transferred million of times?

Comment: I don't see the advantage of ii) since is more code and more data.

Comment: I think it's okay to store JSON in cookies, but as per https://curl.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html about the value: "This string is a sequence of characters excluding semi-colon, comma and white space". So you have to use something like `encodeURIComponent(value)` before storing the cookie.

Answer (score 15):

For that small object, I would definitely put it in the cookie as JSON. Overhead when doing this will be almost none existent and definitely not an issue.

As for what generally works best it's highly dependant on what you have and what you wanna end up with.

Keep in mind:

- It Will produce overhead (from JSON structure, additional characters)
- Choose a better name with a prefix of a name
  like yourappname-something or some random longer string instead of
  the name in order to prevent other apps accidentaly overwriting your cookie
- Large and complex objects = you will have large cookies.
  One can easily go over the **4K size limit** for cookies.
- Everyone can access cookies in the browser (both malicious sites/plugins/etc and humans) it is a good practice that all essential data is encrypted. This is best performed at the backend because if it was ever received unencrypted one can be smart and read that communication.

To solve the 4K limit problem you can put part of the payload in each cookie, but for a lot of data you will end up with a LOT of cookies, and it's not as readable as one would like. If your object has nested objects, **name will begin to look like myapp-object-nested1-nested2-property**. This can be hard to navigate and then put back together when you need a single object from cookies again.

You can go a mix of both approaches - restructuring large objects into COMPOSITION of smaller ones where it makes sense. This will land somewhere in between too large cookies and too many names for small cookies. Try to do it in a way that re-assembly is readable and quick.

**Another option altogether is local or session storage**, the limit is much higher there, so you can dump way bigger JSON directly but you asked about cookies so that is what I focused on.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are concerned about security, it's better to use some one way cryptographic algorithms over original data so that someone with access to user's browser won't be able to read/understand the cookies.

Comment: And how does he decrypt said cookies into data to be used on the front again?

Comment: He should use inverse function of ciphering function/algorithm to decipher.