# Go: how to not remove double quotes on cookies

Tags: go, cookies, double-quotes

Go removes double quotes in cookies.  Is there a way to keep double quotes in cookies in Go?

For example, I'm sending a small JSON message and "SetCookie" strips double quote.

```golang
w.SetCookie("my_cookie_name", small_json_message)
```

More about Cookies:

- The HTTP RFC defines quoted string values.  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6
- The proposed cookie RFC explicitly says double quotes are allowed in cookie values: `cookie-value = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )`
- `;`  is the cookie delimiter.
- Values with ASCII characters outside the limited ASCII range may be quoted (The RFC calls this the `quoted_string`) which expands the allowed character set.
- JSON does not contain the `;` character, so for `;` to appear in JSON it can only appear in string values.  In JSON, string values are already quoted.
- I've confirmed testing using a simple k:v JSON payload and it works fine on all major browsers with no issues.  Of course, the payload cannot be arbitrary, and must be constrained to cookies.
- Cookies are typically generated by server data, not user data.  This means well structured, not arbitrary, JSON may be used
- Go currently has a condition [to insert double quote into cookies](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/net/http/cookie.go;drc=2041bde2b619c8e2cecaa72d986fc1f0d054c615;l=409).

JSON easily can conform to the cookie RFC.  Additionally, even though it's not an issue with this example of JSON, regarding the hypothetical concern of not conforming to the RFC:

- A cookie is transmitted as a HTTP headers.  Many HTTP headers commonly disregard the RFC.  For example, the `Sec-Ch-Ua` header created by Chrome, includes several "bad" characters.

`Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"`

- "comma" is "disallowed" and it's used all the time.
- Even if double quotes were "wrong", which they are not, but if they were, there are lots of in-the-wild examples of cookies containing quotes.

For reference, here's the [relevant section of RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1)

```
set-cookie-header = "Set-Cookie:" SP set-cookie-string
 set-cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-av )
 cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
 cookie-name       = token
 cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
 cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                       ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                       ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                       ; and backslash
```

Where one can see `whitespace DQUOTE` is disallowed and `DQUOTE` is allowed.

For example, [from the author of the RFC](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2017JanMar/0229.html),

`Set-Cookie: foo="bar"`
results in a cookie
`Cookie: foo="bar"` [3](https://github.com/abarth/http-state/blob/master/tests/data/parser/value0002-test) [4](https://github.com/abarth/http-state/blob/master/tests/data/parser/value0002-expected)

Comment: `"` is [not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) in HTTP cookies. But you can always URL-encode it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51173053/1923095
Where JSON is stored in cookies.

Comment: The allowed bytes in a cookie value are pretty limited. You just cannot have arbitrary JSON as a cookie value.

Comment: Volker is correct, arbitrary JSON is not necessarily permitted, but well structured and compliant JSON is.  rustyx is just simple wrong.  The RFC explicitly permits double quotes.  It doesn't allow some combinations of space with double quotes.  You can check for these conditions to ensure compliant cookies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Yes**.  Double quotes are allowed in cookies and other HTTP headers.  Double quotes are also used to escape characters that would be otherwise invalid.

Here's a way to manually set a cookie, where `w` is the http.responseWriter and `b` is the bytes of the cookie. Max-Age is in seconds and 999999999 is ~31.69 years.

```golang
w.Header().Set("Set-Cookie", "your_cookie_name="+string(b)+"; Path=/; Domain=localhost; Secure; Max-Age=999999999; SameSite=Strict")
```

Since you'll probably use cURL to test sending cookies to the server, here's a useful test:

```bash
curl --insecure --cookie 'test1={"test1":"v1"}; test2={"test2":"v2"}'  https://localhost:8081/
```

Which results in a HTTP header like the following:

```
GET / HTTP/2.0
Host: localhost:8081
Accept: */*
Cookie: test1={"test1":"v1"}; test2={"test2":"v2"}
User-Agent: curl/7.0.0
```

Although not the case here and the above is compliant with the RFC, many of the RFC rules are ignored all the time, [especially commas](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/net/http/cookie.go;drc=2041bde2b619c8e2cecaa72d986fc1f0d054c615;l=399).  For example, Chrome sets this header:

```
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
```

Gasp!  Is uses commas and other things!  [It is well established that commas in HTTP headers are okay](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/net/http/cookie.go;drc=2041bde2b619c8e2cecaa72d986fc1f0d054c615;l=399), even though the RFC appears to say otherwise.

Note that the Chrome header uses spaces, many double quotes, commas, special characters, and semi colon.  Chrome here uses double quotes around many values needing escaping, and that's the right way to be compliant with the RFC.

Note that the cookie RFC 6265 is a *proposal* and has been for 11 years.  There are reasons for that.  Knowing that cookies are just a HTTP header, look at the accepted HTTP RFC for quoted string semantic for header values:

[HTTP RFC 7230 3.2.6.](https://%20https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6)

These characters are included for `quoted-string`:

HTAB, SP
!#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
%x80-FF

The characters " and / may be included if escaped.

Answer (score 2):

> HTTP cookies are allowed to have double quotes.

Are you sure? [rfc6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265) states:

```
set-cookie-header = "Set-Cookie:" SP set-cookie-string
set-cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-av )
cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name       = token
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                       ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                       ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                       ; and backslash
```

So it appears that Go is following the specification (the spec previously defines`DQUOTE` to mean `double quote`).

See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10195) for further information.

Comment: A cookie value is explicitly allowed to have double quotes: `cookie-value = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )`

Comment: Quotes may be used to wrap the octet; however, if present, these will generally be stripped when the value is extracted. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) - "A <cookie-value> can optionally be wrapped in double quotes and include any US-ASCII characters excluding control characters, Whitespace, double quotes, comma, semicolon, and backslash."

Comment: No, it is not stripped, but if it was, stripped by who?  The browser and tools like curl preserve quotes.  Inside `quoted_string`, quote and backslash simply need to be escaped with a backslash.  They can't be included without escaping, but may be included with escaping.

Comment: Sorry - I'm confused. Your original question was asking why the quotes are stripped but now you say "it is not stripped"? In the case of Go `SetCookie` [strips the quotes here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/net/http/cookie.go;l=403;drc=c55d184151d2a1d313b96d8e835341cd1f0ec0c5). See the issue I linked for the thoughts of some of the authors of the standard library (discussing further here is of minimal value given the statements there).

Comment: Sorry, see my answer below.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68582863/1923095

The question was "how" not "why".  Imho, Go was wrong to strip quotes so cavalierly, just as that same section of code used to be wrong in stripping commas. See https://github.com/Cyphrme/Coze/blob/10897b1a0c6ddbecc1f892759e440f254a625edf/docs/http_headers.md?plain=1#L124

Consider this Chrome HTTP header: 
`Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"`

which is considered valid HTTP.

Comment: "how" not "why" - The how is fairly simple - copy the `http.Cookie` code and alter it to meet your needs. There are a range of specs in this area with conflicting info, and common applications that ignore all of the specs. The Go authors had to make a decision and they decided to remove quotes ([here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46443) is another open issue regarding quotes).

Comment: Fantastic reference.  Thank you for the link.